# How do I prevent prerequisite files from being duplicated in the app deployment folder?

Tags: winforms, clickonce, publishing, prerequisites

I have a .NET 3.5 SP1 WinForms application.  I have set it up for ClickOnce deployment with the following settings:

[image: Prerequisite and deployment settings screenshot in Visual Studio 2008]

- Publish to location: \\fileserver\installers\myapp\
- Prerequisites: Windows Installer 3.1, .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
- Download prerequisites from the following location: \\fileserver\installers\common\
- Application is available offline (installs to Add/Remove Programs and Start Menu)

It is likely that our users will not have internet access or 3.5 installed already.  Since they will all be on the company intranet, we've put the necessary installers on a network share location they'll all be able to access.

When testing installation on a machine that lacks .NET 3.5, everything works fine.  It installs the prereqs and the app and it launches no problem.

The problem is that every time I deploy the application (via the Publish button) Visual Studio 2008 insists on copying all of the prerequisite files/folders from my development PC to the network location (installers\myapp).  This causes my 20MB application to be about 200MB in the folder.  This effectively duplicates everything since the ~200MB prereqs are already in the installers\common folder.  As I said, though, it installs fine.  It even installs fine if I delete the prereqs that VS puts in the myapp folder, presumably because the installer is getting them from the common location anyway (as specified in the Prerequisites dialog).

This is perhaps a trivial issue, since nothing goes wrong and it'll work fine, but it is annoying for two reasons:

1. It slows down deployment since I have to transfer 200+ megs over the wire every time I publish a small change to the application
2. It wastes space on our file server

I can resolve the second issue by simply deleting the folders every time, but that in itself is an annoying extra step.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is roll your own prerequisites using the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator. Set the URL to the location where you want to serve up the deployment. Then set the option in VS to "download from vendor location".

It will download the deployment from the URL you set in the BMG, and won't deploy the prerequisites each time you publish the ClickOnce application.

Comment: Did you try it? Although it has not been updated, I find that it still works.